# Data not populating on page after processing post request

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

it shows data when get request is send properly but when i save data with post requset then again the page is rendered data is not coming on page

This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/incident", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add_incident(Model model,HttpSession session) {

    try{
    List<AddIncident> fetchincident = incService.fetchIncident();
    String user_id = ""+session.getAttribute("session");

    List<AddIncident> fetchuserincident = incService.fetchuserincident(user_id);

    //group work

            User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    List<User> fetchListByUsername = userService.findListByUserName(user_id);

    String department = fetchListByUsername.get(0).getDepartment();
    List<AddIncident> fetchgroupincident = incService.fetchgroupincident(department);

    System.out.println(fetchgroupincident.get(0).getAssignTo());
    System.out.println(fetchgroupincident.get(0).getSeverity());
    model.addAttribute("fetchincident", fetchincident);
    model.addAttribute("fetchgroupincident", fetchgroupincident);
    model.addAttribute("fetchuserincident", fetchuserincident);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    }

    AddIncident incident = new AddIncident();
    model.addAttribute("incident", incident);


    return "incident";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/incident", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add_incident(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("incident") AddIncident incident,
        BindingResult result, Model model,HttpSession session) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "incident";
    } else {

        User user=new User();
        System.out.println(""+session.getAttribute("session"));
        String user_id = ""+session.getAttribute("session");
        System.out.println(user_id);

        List<User> fetchListByUsername = userService.findListByUserName(user_id);

        String department = fetchListByUsername.get(0).getDepartment();
        System.out.println(department);

        try{
        List<User> fetchgroupuser = userService.findListByGroup(department);


        ArrayList<String> email=new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println(email);
        for(User use:fetchgroupuser){
            email.add(use.getEmail());
        }

        String[] to = new String[email.size()];
        to = email.toArray(to);
        System.out.println(to);

                /*new String[]{"irasoftwares6@gmail.com","bluemagictest@gmail.com"};*/
        String from = "Anurag.yv19@gmail.com";
        String sub= "Incident Management System"; 
        String msgBody="New Incident created"; 
        incService.save(incident);




        emailService.sendEmail(to , from, sub, msgBody);
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        incident_logger.log(INCIDENT, incident.getRef_id()+"   \n Assigned to :"+session.getAttribute("session"));
        model.addAttribute("message", "Saved incident details");
        return "incident";
    }
}
```

my jsp code

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="inc-table" style="min-height: 280px;">
                <form action="" method="get">
            <div class="input-group">
                <!-- USE TWITTER TYPEAHEAD JSON WITH API TO SEARCH -->
                <input class="form-control" id="system-search" name="q" placeholder="Search for" required>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>

                <table  class="table table-list-search table-bordered table-stripped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ref. No.</th>
                            <th>Created</th>
                            <th>Severity</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Assigned</th>
                            <th>Est</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Config-item</th>
                            <th>Symptom Code</th>
                            <th>Closure Code</th>
                            <th>Submitted BY</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="fetchuserincident" items="${fetchuserincident}">
                        <tr>

                            <td id="1" class="click" ><a href=""/>${fetchuserincident.ref_id}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.created}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.severity}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.state}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.assignTo}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.escalation}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.description}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.location}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.config_Item}</td>

                            <td>${fetchuserincident.symptom_code}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.closure_code}</td>
                            <td>${fetchuserincident.submittedby}</td>
                            <td> <button id="editbtn" class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</button></td>

                            </tr>
                                            </c:forEach>

                    </tbody>

                </table>




            </div>

            <hr>
            <br>
```

**My Group Work**
                    
                
                    
                    
                    
                        
                    
                
            

                    
                        
                            
                                Ref. No.
                                Created
                                Severity
                                State
                                Assigned
                                Est
                                Description
                                Location
                                Config-item
                                Symptom Code
                                Closure Code
                                Submitted BY
                            
                        
                            
                            
                            

                                ${fetchgroupincident.ref_id}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.created}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.severity}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.state}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.assignTo}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.escalation}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.description}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.location}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.config_Item}
                                    ${fetchgroupincident.symptom_code}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.closure_code}
                                ${fetchgroupincident.submittedby}


                                         Edit

Comment: Why should it, you haven't put it in the model again... Hence nothing is there, the model is empty for each request (basically) and will only contain things you put in it (except for the already provided model attribute(s)). Instead of populating the lists in the GET method, move that code to a method annotated with  `@ModelAttribute` that method will be invoked before each request handling method and as such will fill your model.

Comment: OR issue a redirect to the view, which will in turn invoke the GET method.

Comment: yes ,the redirect works thanks a lot M. Deinum